# Javascript for Zip Code validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm attempting to have Javascript validate a user-entered zip code.

If it is within the list of valid zip codes, it should take them to a new page to schedule an appointment. If the zip code isn't in the listing, it should display a message that says that it isn't covered by the service area and then keep them on the page.

I have it working to where it takes them to the appointment page if it's valid, but it also takes them to the appointment page if it isn't valid.

Would you guys mind helping me figure this out?

Here is the page the Javascript is running on: http://platinumfactoryservice.com/service-area/

Below is the code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function checkZip() {

var z = document.myform.zip;
var zv = z.value;
if (!/^\d{5}$/.test(zv)) {
alert ("Please enter a valid Zip Code");
document.myform.zip.value = "";
myfield = z;  // note myfield must be a global variable
setTimeout('myfield.focus(); myfield.select();' , 10);  // to fix bug in Firefox
return false;
}

var codes = [26003,26030,26031,26032,26035,26036,26037,26038,26039,26040,26041,26058,26059,26060,26062,26070,26074,26075,43713,43716,43718,43719,43747,43750,43757,43759,43768,43773,43778,43902,43905,43906,43909,43912,43913,43915,43916,43917,43927,43928,43933,43934,43935,43937,43938,43939,43940,43941,43942,43943,43947,43948,43950,43951,43952,43953,43963,43967,43971,43972,43977,43985,15004,15017,15018,15019,15021,15025,15028,15031,15034,15035,15045,15046,15047,15053,15054,15055,15056,15057,15060,15064,15071,15078,15081,15082,15088,15102,15104,15106,15108,15110,15112,15116,15120,15122,15123,15126,15127,15129,15131,15132,15133,15134,15135,15136,15137,15139,15140,15142,15143,15145,15146,15147,15148,15201,15202,15203,15204,15205,15206,15207,15208,15209,15210,15211,15212,15213,15214,15215,15216,15217,15218,15219,15220,15221,15222,15223,15224,15225,15226,15227,15228,15229,15230,15231,15232,15233,15234,15235,15236,15237,15239,15240,15241,15242,15243,15244,15250,15251,15252,15253,15254,15255,15257,15258,15259,15260,15261,15262,15264,15265,15267,15268,15270,15272,15274,15275,15276,15277,15278,15279,15281,15282,15283,15286,15289,15290,15295,15301,15312,15317,15321,15323,15339,15340,15342,15350,15361,15363,15365,15367,15376,15378,15379,15347,15330,23705,23703,23707,23708,23704,23709,23702,23701,23326,23328,23327,23322,23325,23320,23324,23323,23321,23520,23519,23541,23512,23551,23515,23529,23506,23501,23514,23521,23518,23502,23503,23505,23513,23509,23504,23508,23511,23517,23510,23507,23523,23459,23458,23450,23479,23471,23466,23467,23465,23463,23461,23451,23460,23456,23452,23455,23454,23453,23462,23464,23457,23261,23291,23260,23225,23221,23249,23222,23223,23241,23232,23224,23290,23173,23298,23273,23274,23289,23279,23282,23276,23278,23295,23219,23218,23220,23269,23286,23292,23293,23285,23284,23228,23227,23226,23229,23075,23231,23230,23294,23289,23060,23059,23075,23288,23242,23238,23250,23233,23255,23150,23058,23234,23831,23235,23237,23236,23836,23114,23112,23113,23297,23832,23120,23838,23801,23803,23804,23805,23806,23834,23111,15004,15017,15018,15019,15021,15025,15028,15031,15034,15035,15045,15046,15047,15053,15054,15055,15056,15057,15060,15064,15071,15078,15081,15082,15084,15088,15102,15104,15106,15108,15110,15112,15116,15120,15122,15123,15126,15127,15129,15131,15132,15133,15134,15135,15136,15137,15139,15140,15142,15143,15145,15146,15147,15148,15201,15202,15203,15204,15205,15206,15207,15208,15209,15210,15211,15212,15213,15214,15215,15216,15217,15218,15219,15220,15221,15222,15223,15224,15225,15226,15227,15228,15229,15230,15231,15232,15233,15234,15235,15236,15237,15239,15240,15241,15242,15243,15244,15250,15251,15252,15253,15254,15255,15257,15258,15259,15260,15261,15262,15264,15265,15267,15268,15270,15272,15274,15275,15276,15277,15278,15279,15281,15282,15283,15286,15289,15290,15295,15301,15312,15317,15321,15323,15339,15340,15342,15350,15361,15363,15365,15367,15376,15378,15379,15347,15330,43711,43717,43722,43723,43724,43725,43732,43736,43772,43778,43779,43780,43788,25504,25510,25526,25537,25541,25545,25559,25571,25701,25702,25703,25704,25705,25706,25707,25708,25709,25710,25711,25712,25713,25714,25715,25716,25717,25718,25719,25720,25721,25722,25723,25724,25725,25726,25727,25728,25729,25755,25770,25771,25772,25773,25774,25775,25776,25777,25778,25779,41101,41102,41105,41114,41129,41139,41169,41183,45619,45619,45623,45638,45645,45669,45675,45680,25011,25026,25033,25070,25082,25109,25112,25124,25143,25156,25159,25168,25177,25213,25334,25338,25357,25375,25389,25560,25569,25003,25015,25025,25035,25039,25045,25054,25061,25064,25067,25071,25075,25079,25083,25086,25102,25103,25107,25110,25126,25132,25134,25160,25162,25201,25202,25214,25301,25302,25303,25304,25305,25306,25309,25311,25312,25313,25314,25315,25317,25320,25321,25322,25323,25324,25325,25326,25327,25328,25329,25330,25331,25332,25333,25335,25336,25337,25339,25350,25356,25358,25360,25361,25362,25364,25365,25387,25392,25396,15001,15003,15005,15009,15010,15026,15027,15042,15043,15050,15052,15059,15061,15066,15074,15077,15081,16123,16136,16101,16102,16103,16105,16107,16108,16112,16115,16116,16117,16120,16121,16123,16132,16140,16141,16142,16143,16146,16148,16150,16155,16156,16157,16159,16160,16161,16172,44401,44403,44405,44406,44416,44418,44420,44422,44424,44425,44429,44430,44436,44437,44438,44440,44442,44443,44446,44451,44452,44454,44470,44471,44473,44481,44482,44483,44484,44485,44486,44488,44501,44502,44503,44504,44505,44506,44507,44509,44510,44511,44512,44513,44514,44515,44555,44619,44672,16001,16002,16003,16016,16017,16018,16020,16021,16022,16023,16024,16025,16027,16029,16030,16033,16034,16035,16037,16038,16039,16040,16041,16045,16046,16048,16050,16051,16052,16053,16055,16056,16057,16059,16061,16063,16066,15006,15007,15014,15015,15024,15030,15032,15037,15044,15049,15051,15065,15075,15076,15086,15090,15091,15101,15144,15238,44609,44701,44702,44703,44704,44705,44706,44707,44708,44709,44710,44711,44714,44718,44720,44720,44721,44730,44730,44735,44750,44767,44799,44601,44646,44647,44648,44608,44613,44614,44626,44630,44632,44640,44641,44643,44650,44652,44657,44662,44666,44669,44670,44685,44688,44689,44056,44067,44087,44203,44210,44216,44221,44222,44223,44224,44232,44232,44236,44237,44250,44260,44262,44264,44278,44286,44301,44302,44303,44304,44305,44306,44307,44308,44309,44310,44311,44313,44314,44315,44316,44317,44319,44320,44321,44325,44326,44328,44333,44334,44334,44372,44396,44398,44632,44685,44280,44256,44254,44281,44273,44258,44274,44233,44215,44235,44251,44253,44212,44282,44275,44240];  // add as many zip codes as you like, separated by commas (no comma at the end)
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<codes.length; i++) {
if (zv == codes[i]) {
found = true;
break;
}
}

if (!found) {
alert("Sorry, the Zip Code " + zv + " is not covered by our business");
return false;
//do nothing
```

} else {
    alert("The Zip Code " + zv + " is covered by our service team. Please press okay to go forward to schedule an appointment");
    document.myform.submit();
}
    }

```
</script>
```

Comment: Postal code validation is a difficult problem because new postal codes are introduced all the time.

Comment: Is it your custom postal code listing? or real time data

Comment: I have a listing of valid codes, that I may have to keep updated, but otherwise they service a select area of zip codes.

Comment: It is my custom code listing.

Comment: Just paste you code. It might require some simple modification

Comment: He posted a link with the code quite clearly in it, true it would have been better if he had posted it in his question to prevent link rot, but if you would have checked the link you wouldn't have needed to ask that comment in the first place.

Comment: I think you should change the title of your post. It's not about zipcode validation but it's some redirect problem.

Comment: I have added the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `onsubmit="checkZip()"` to `onsubmit="return checkZip()"`, because right now your form is always submitted.

Comment: ... or, alternatively, add `type="button"` to the `<button>` tag, since the function explicitly submits the form when it thinks the zip is OK.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thanks so much! Do you think it would be more beneficial to change it from an alert to an error below the submit button if it isn't validated? Is this easy to do?

Comment: In general it's advised to never use alerts, so that's definitely something to consider yes (a few google searched should solve that if you don't know how).

Comment: Agreed. Go with on-page notifications if possible, including when you say that the zip _is_ in the service area. Get rid of that alert, instead put a "Congratulations, you're in the area" type notice on the second page. Oh, and don't forget to do server-side zip code validation as well.

Comment: In this case there is no security issue involved, so server side validation isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance. I think I have it working properly now. I appreciate your help!